# Collections of objects with of the same "raw type" but varying type parameter

Tags: c#, generics

In Java you can write a static method that reverses every `List` in a collection:

```
public static void reverseAll(Collection<List<?>> lists) {
    for (List<?> list : lists)
        Collections.reverse(list);
}
```

I run into difficulty when I try to do somehing similar in C# because the interfaces `IList<T>` as `T` varies do not share a common interface with a `Reverse` method. I have found that you can do it using the `dynamic` type:

```
public static void ReverseAll(IEnumerable<dynamic> lists)
{
     foreach (dynamic list in lists)
        list.Reverse();
}
```

I don't like this approach as there is nothing to stop you passing in an `IEnumerable` which does not consist of `ILists`, and you lose all compile-time checking. Is there a better solution to this sort of thing?

Comment: Our of curiosity, what's your use case for passing a collection of lists of multiple Ts into a method for reversing each individual list?

Comment: Good question! I don't have one. It was just an example to demonstrate an issue I've encountered. In reality I've created a generic class Bin<T> of recently deleted items of type T and a method Restore to restore them all. I want my application to have a Restore All button. In Java, it's easy, but in C# it seems a lot trickier if the types can vary.

Comment: You can go for `object` instead of `dynamic` but it's hardly any better in terms of complie-time checking.

Comment: I know this is not really what you ask for, but with arrays, which are not really generically typed, you *can* do this: `public static void ReverseAll(IEnumerable<Array> lists) { foreach (Array list in lists) { Array.Reverse(list); } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, generic interfaces that include members that don't care about the generic type would--rather than implementing such members directly--inherit from a non-generic base interface that provides them.  For example, `IList<T>` could have inherited from an `IPermutableSequence` interface which includes methods like `Count`, `Reverse`, `Swap`, `RotateRange`, etc.  Had `IList<T>` been derived from such a base, the kind of behavior you seek could have been implemented easily.

Unfortunately, if the things in your collection implement generic interfaces which are not covariant and have no useful common base type, there's no nice way to achieve the behavior you seek.  Instead, it will be necessary to use Reflection on the type of each object instance to determine if it's a `List<>` and, if so, extract the generic type parameter and use that to generate and invoke a `ListReverse<T>` method.  Not totally impossible, but icky.

Since you haven't described your actual usage scenario, it's unclear whether there would be any possibility of extracting non-generic methods to a non-generic interface and using that.  Such an approach is apt to be much faster and cleaner than anything using Reflection.

Comment: Thanks. I posted the question just for confirmation that you basically can't do it in any nice way - I'm surprised it's taken so long! I'm so used to Java that the differences to C# will take a while to get used to.

Comment: @pbabcdefp: There are a few places where type erasure can be helpful, though most of those could be handled via the use of type-independent interfaces. For example, if there existed an `ITypedList` interface had included a `TryAdd(Object o)` method which would indicate whether the object in question could be added, and if `IList<T>` inherited from that, one could do with `ITypedList` just about everything one could do with Java's `List<>`.

Comment: I agree it can sometimes be helpful, but the fact that you can't access type information at runtime is very irritating. I bet everyone who tries to write generic methods in java writes `T.class` at least once. My favourite consequence of java's implementation though is that you can have non-generic static methods, because the classes `GenericType<T>` are actually all the same.

Comment: @pbabcdefp: The .NET approach is 99.44% better, except in cases where the designers of interfaces failed to have them inherit a non-generic interface which includes all the methods that shouldn't care about the generic type.  Unfortunately, as noted earlier, most of the generic interfaces in the .NET framework are rather limited in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

Use a marker interface for T

```
public static void ReverseAll<T>(IEnumerable<List<T>> lists) where T : YourMarkerInterface
```

Then apply the interface to all T's that could be in your collection